# How to print a value in console application C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, console-application

This is the code which running on my console.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string X = GeneratePassword();
    Console.WriteLine("The password = ", X);
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

My `GeneratePassword` function is returning value for sure, but somehow I am unable to print it. I might be missing a small thing. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `GeneratePassword` returns string.

Comment: With C# 6.0 your could write _Console.WriteLine($"The password = {X}");_

Comment: I am using C# 4.0 @Steve...anyway thanks for mentioning

Comment: C# 6.0 is a matter of your compiler. If you are working with Visual Studio 2015 you can use that syntax without changing anything else. Try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

**To**

```
 Console.WriteLine("The password = "+ X);
```

**or**

```
Console.WriteLine("The password = {0}", X);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it either way:

```
Console.WriteLine("The password = " + x);
```

Or either

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The password = {0}", x));
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
Console.WriteLine("The password = ", X);
```

With

```
Console.WriteLine("The password = {0}", X);
```

You are missing a placeholder for your variable.
If you had more variables, it would be

```
 Console.WriteLine("The password = {0} and other value {1}", X, Y);
```

EDIT:
You can also use

```
Console.WriteLine("The password = "+ X);
//or note the $ sign before string. It will render variables inside {} 
Console.WriteLine($"The password = {X}");
```

Comment: I am returning a single string, why should I use your 3rd code block??

Comment: @Arka_Dev I gave you an example why your code does not work, and provided you with more info how to use a solution if you had more than one variable.

Comment: Sure, more of a generalistic approach.anyway thanks for mentioning

Comment: np. I added more examples you could use :)